# Sharepoint List View exceed threshold but still able to see

Tags: listview, sharepoint-2013, threshold

**UPDATE** I acknowledged that the warning only show if the view has filter, count, sort... condition. A default flat view won't be restricted by threshold

I am new to SharePoint 2013 and facing a weird issue.

I created a List with more than 6k items by publishing from excel. After that, I assign a user to Member group of site. However, when the user views the list, they are not warned about the list view exceeds 5000 item threshold. This happens with both the default Allitems.aspx view and newly-created view.
I check List Setting again under System Account privilege and there's still warning there

```
"6826 items (list view threshold is 5000).
The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold, which is 5000 items. Tasks that cause excessive server load (such as those involving all list items) are currently prohibited."
```

Any explaination why user can still see all items ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I acknowledged that the warning only show if the view has filter, count, sort... conditions. A default flat view won't be restricted by threshold